# How to get all descendants of a node with Django mptt?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-mptt, descendant

I would like my categories to show all items in that category including descendant categories, so the parent category contains all items for subcategories.

I have tried adding this method to my Category class in models.py

```py
def get_all_products(self):
    # To display all items from all subcategories
    return Product.objects.filter(category__in=Category.objects.get_descendants(include_self=True))
```

And added this to my template.html, but it does't work. What am I doing wrong?

```
    <li>{{ product.product_name }}</li>
{% empty %}
     <li>No items</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've realised where I was going wrong, the correct code is:

`def get_all_products(self):
        # To display all items from all subcategories
        return Product.objects.filter(category__in=self.get_descendants(include_self=True))`

`{% for product in product.get_all_products %}
    <li>{{ product.product_name }}</li>
{% empty %}
     <li>No items</li>
{% endfor %}`

Answer (score 1):

In view function I use:

```
 products = models.Product.objects.filter(category__in=category.get_descendants(include_self=True))
```

Answer (score 0):

For example, you can get all descendants of a category with [get_descendants()](https://django-mptt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/models.html#get-descendants-include-self-false) in `views.py` as shown below. *If `include_self` is `True`, the `QuerySet` will also include the model instance itself and I don't recommend to use [Django mptt](https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt) which is currently unmaintained. Intead, use [Django treebeard](https://github.com/django-treebeard/django-treebeard):

```py
# "views.py"

from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Category, Product

def test(request):
    categories = Category.objects.get(name="Food").get_descendants()
    print(categories) 
    # <TreeQuerySet [<Category: Meat>, <Category: Fish>]>

    categories = Category.objects.get(name="Food").get_descendants(include_self=True)
    print(categories) 
    # <TreeQuerySet [<Category: Food>, <Category: Meat>, <Category: Fish>]>

    products = Product.objects.filter(category__in=categories)
    print(products)
    # <QuerySet [<Product: Beef>, <Product: Pork>, <Product: Salmon>

    return HttpResponse("Test")
```